# Elastic search sorting by author last name

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Is there any analyzer that i can use to tokenize only the last word in the text?

i am using the custom code to split the text into first word and last word in C# and then using that last word as the sort field. I am just curious is there anything available in elastic search to do the same?

- Author - Jorge Cruise  Sort - Cruise
- Author - Bruce Lansky Sort - Lansky
- Author -  Carol Fenster,Bruce Lansky  Sort - Fenster

Answer (score 0):

Why not create separate fields for the first and last name?  I don't believe you can sort like that, since the "inverted index" doesn't care about the order: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html

Comment: i am using separate field for now, i was looking if elastic search had any analyses to tokenise or skip the first name and have only last name